How to protect smart pointer's address from scope lifespan in c++
I am working on a C++ code in which I deal with shared_ptr<Toto> (where Toto is an arbitrary object); let's say a.
And for some technical reasons, I also have to store the address of these pointers for extra manipulation somewhere else, so I have a std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Toto>> which is the address attribute of a class addressBook.
Before, you start bashing me, I know, such pointer of pointer is in most of the case a sign of a bad architecture ; However in this particular case, my coworker and I arrived to the conclusion that was this only way for this code. Otherwise, you can see it as an exercise in style, and it does not change the nature of the question.
The problem is that a (std::shared_ptr<Toto>) and book.address (std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Toto>>) are not necessarily declared in the same scope, so don't have the same life-span.
With this difference of scope, I can access to the address and the value of a (std::shared_ptr<Toto>) after its destruction through book.address (std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Toto>>), so this can lead to unsafe situations.
I came up with a workaround using an additional watcher named tmp_proxy (std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Toto>>) containing a deleter custom_deleter and the address of the std::shared_ptr<Toto>& sptr that I need to declare in the scope, so they should have the same life-span.
But I am sure that is safe and I found it cumbersome.
Here is a MWE:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Toto {
public:
    double hello;

    ~Toto() {
        std::cout << "Destructor Toto with value " << hello << std::endl;
    }
};

int status = 0; // global variable

void custom_deleter(std::shared_ptr<Toto>* ptr) {
    std::cout << "WOW WOW I should make sure that "<< ptr->get()->hello << " at " << (ptr) <<" is not accessible anymore !" << std::endl;
    status += 1; // Increment status
    //delete ptr;  // Actually delete the object
};

class addressBook {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Toto>> address;
    std::weak_ptr<Toto> Waddress;
    
    std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Toto>> add_watcher(std::shared_ptr<Toto>& sptr) {
         std::cout << "add watcher" << std::endl;
         std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Toto>> a_watch_addr(&sptr, custom_deleter);
         auto nullDeleter = [](void*) {};
         address.reset(&sptr, nullDeleter);

         Waddress=sptr;
         return a_watch_addr;
    };

    void modify(std::shared_ptr<Toto>& sptr) {
         std::cout << "modify " << std::endl;
         *address= sptr;
         Waddress=sptr;
         return;
    };

    void observe(int i) {
        std::cout << "addressBook "<< i<<" address "<< address << " ; *address "<< *address.get() << " ; *address->value "<< address->get()->hello << std::endl;
        if (auto ptr = Waddress.lock()) {
            std::cout << "addressBook *Waddress->value "<< ptr->hello << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "addressBook is dead Waddress"<< std::endl;
        }
         return;
    };
    
    
    ~addressBook() {
        std::cout << "Destructor addressBook with address " << address << std::endl;
    };
};

int main() {
    { // First scope
        std::shared_ptr<Toto> b = std::make_shared<Toto>();
        addressBook book;
        b->hello = 3.14;
        { // Opening second scope
            std::shared_ptr<Toto> a = std::make_shared<Toto>();
            a->hello = 666.666;
            std::shared_ptr<Toto> c = std::make_shared<Toto>();
            c->hello = 111.2;
            std::cout << "at init: a=" <<a << " ; &a=" << &a 
                <<" and b=" <<b << " ; &b=" << &b  
                <<" and c=" <<c << " ; &c=" << &c  << std::endl;

            std::cout << "first a receives a new_deleter" << std::endl;
            auto tmp_proxy= book.add_watcher(a);
            book.observe(1);

            book.modify(b); // now a = b
            book.observe(2);
            std::cout << "after modification: a->hello=" <<a->hello << " ; a=" <<a << " ; &a=" << &a << std::endl;

            std::cout << "and a is redirected to point to c" << std::endl;
            a = c;
            book.observe(3);
            std::cout << "OUPS Waddress is not following a!" << std::endl;

            std::cout << "a & c will be destroyed by end of scope =>Wow should appear AFTER this point" << std::endl;
        } // Closing second scope
        book.observe(4);
        std::cout << "OUPS address is unsafe!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "now b and Book will be destroyed:" << std::endl;
    } // Closing first scope -> b is out of scope
    std::cout << "b and Book got destroyed" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "END MAIN with status " << status << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

and here is the output:
first a receives a new_deleter
add watcher
addressBook 1 address 0x7fff3edf6910 ; *address 0x13d72e0 ; *address->value 666.666
addressBook *Waddress->value 666.666
modify 
Destructor Toto with value 666.666
addressBook 2 address 0x7fff3edf6910 ; *address 0x13d72c0 ; *address->value 3.14
addressBook *Waddress->value 3.14
after modification: a->hello=3.14 ; a=0x13d72c0 ; &a=0x7fff3edf6910
and a is redirected to point to c
addressBook 3 address 0x7fff3edf6910 ; *address 0x13d7300 ; *address->value 111.2
addressBook *Waddress->value 3.14
OUPS Waddress is not following a!
a & c will be destroyed by end of scope =>Wow should appear AFTER this point
WOW WOW I should make sure that 111.2 at 0x7fff3edf6910 is not accessible anymore !
Destructor Toto with value 111.2
addressBook 4 address 0x7fff3edf6910 ; *address 0x13d7300 ; *address->value 111.2
addressBook *Waddress->value 3.14
OUPS address is unsafe!
now b and Book will be destroyed:
Destructor addressBook with address 0x7fff3edf6910
Destructor Toto with value 3.14
b and Book got destroyed
END MAIN with status 1

So my questions are:

Is it possible to observe the address of <std::shared_ptr<Toto> a (and not the address of content) to determine when it is destroyed ?
This in order to execute a function at that moment to make sure I will not try to access this address anymore.
Is there any better way to do it, that my ugly idea ? if not really, is it safe ?

edit
I added the modify to illustrate that sometimes I have to perform operation on a through its address (aka the pointer of pointer), while sometimes I have to perform simply on a (like a=c;).
I hope this will clarify why such complexity.

I still try to understand the question and the code. But at a first read it sound like you want to use std::weak_ptr at those places. And in the watcher once you "hit" a weak_ptr that is not pointing to a shared_ptr remove that from that list.

There are several code smells here: (ptr).get() is a weird way of spelling ptr->get(), and that can also give you a null pointer, which you never check for. Using a null deleter for a shared pointer is a hack to get a shared pointer to something that you don't allocate dynamically and that you don't have control over. Taking the address of a reference you receive in a function and storing that is just asking for trouble that even the use of smart pointers can't fix for you. One final question for me remains: What are you trying to achieve there?

Your use-case is really vague, so it is hard to tell how a correct solution would look like. You say  [...]I also have to store the address of these pointers for extra manipulation somewhere else [...] The problem is that a  and book.address are not necessarily [...] have the same life-span [...]  I can access to the address and the value of a  after its destruction [...] If both would just be std::shared_ptr<Toto> then this would not happend, that's the purpose of a shared pointer. So why would the usage of std::shared_ptr<Toto> alone not work for you?

@t.niese I edited my question in order to clarify why I use std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Toto>> yet trying to keep it simple (not always easy). I also add my naive understanding of how I would use a std::weak_ptr<Toto> (in fact or a simple std::shared_ptr<Toto>) and why I am not able to do what I want with it. I hope it will be clearer.

@UlrichEckhardt thank you for pointing this ugly syntax, I tried to improved it.

You still don't show anything that needs a pointer to a pointer. Just do *a = *c instead of a = c

@Caleth Indeed, *a=*c will give the illusion that the weak_ptr followed. But this is a copy of the c content into a, and this in not a pointer redirection. For example, if after doing *a=*c I do c->hello=0.1; then a->hello will still be equal to 111.2 . While with the redirection a=c; c->hello=0.1; then a->hello will still be equal to 0.1. About "showing anything that needs a pointer to a pointer", if you have a solution to do both book.modify(b); // now a = b and a = c; // with now book.something pointing to c without  a pointer to a pointer, then I will take it :)


The problem is that a (std::shared_ptr) and book.address (std::shared_ptrstd::shared_ptr<Toto>) are not necessarily declared in the same scope, so don't have the same life-span.

No, the problem is that the scope of a cannot possibly share ownership of a std::shared_ptr<Toto> with book.address.
Let's forget for a moment the exact type std::shared_ptr<Toto>, and call it Wrapper. What you want is for a, c and addressBook::address to all be std::shared_ptr<Wrapper>. Now they can all share ownership of the underlying Wrapper. You don't need to fake sharing ownership.
{ 
    // First scope
    std::shared_ptr<Wrapper> b = std::make_shared<Wrapper>();
    addressBook book;
    b->hello() = 3.14;
    { // Opening second scope
        std::shared_ptr<Wrapper> a = std::make_shared<Wrapper>();
        a->hello() = 666.666;
        std::shared_ptr<Wrapper> c = std::make_shared<Wrapper>();
        c->hello() = 111.2;
        std::cout << "at init: a=" << a->hello() << " ; &a=" << a.get() 
            <<" and b=" << b->hello() << " ; &b=" << b.get()  
            <<" and c=" << c->hello() << " ; &c=" << c.get()  << std::endl;

        std::cout << "first a receives a new_deleter" << std::endl;
        book.add_watcher(a);
        book.observe(1);

        book.modify(b); // now a = b
        book.observe(2);
        std::cout << "after modification: a->hello=" <<a->hello() << " ; &a=" << a.get() << std::endl;

        std::cout << "a & c will be destroyed at end of scope, but *a and *c live on" << std::endl;
        *a = *c;
        book.observe(3);

        std::cout << "a & c will be destroyed by end of scope" << std::endl;
    } // Closing second scope
    book.observe(4);
    std::cout << "now b and Book will be destroyed:" << std::endl;
}

Now we just need to define Wrapper. You could using Wrapper = std::shared_ptr<Toto>;, but to make it more ergonomic, let's use a struct:
struct Wrapper
{
    std::shared_ptr<Toto> ptr = std::make_shared<Toto>();
    double& hello() { return ptr->hello; }
};

Now you can modify a or *a to your hearts content, and pass around shared pointers to and from addressBook.
class addressBook {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Wrapper> address;
    
    void add_watcher(std::shared_ptr<Wrapper> sptr) {
         address = sptr;
    };

    void modify(std::shared_ptr<Wrapper>& sptr) {
         std::cout << "modify " << std::endl;
         sptr = address;
    };

    void observe(int i) {
        std::cout << "addressBook "<< i <<" address "<< address->hello() << " ; *address "<< address.get() << std::endl;
    };
        
    ~addressBook() {
        std::cout << "Destructor addressBook with address " << address.get() << std::endl;
    };
};


I was excited about your solution, so I tried it on my real example. But, I realized that it was not possible to follow when a was moving (like when a=c for example). I edit my question with that scenario to illustrate what I understood of your solution and why in my understanding the address is not following. (sorry if my question was not clear enough from the first time).

Yes you updated answer seems cleaner than my solution. But just to make sure that I understood well: you use pointer to pointers everywhere ? and I guess this is to sure that the ownership and lifespan are manage correctly.

@R.N No, I use objects that may have pointer members, and pointers to those. Almost certainly you can find a meaningful name to replace Wrapper from your domain
